# XPS 13 without Ubuntu. Can I take it to an OEM state?

Tags: system-installation, dell, xps, oem

I'm considering buying a refurbished XPS 13. The problem is that it doesn't come with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Can I get it to a point where is similar to the OEM version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. simply install Ubuntu 12.04.

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/dell/dellxps

How: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall